# Request for Assistance - Displaying Time on the Horizontal Axis and Dates on the Vertical Axis

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I hope this message finds you well. I currently use the full calendar in my project and would like to achieve a specific display format where the horizontal axis represents time and the vertical axis represents dates. However, I have been unable to find a built-in option or configuration to accomplish this.

I have explored the full calendar documentation and tried various configurations, but none seem to provide the desired outcome. I would like to have a view that combines the time and date axes, allowing me to visualize events in this format.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality with the full calendar? If not, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how I could customize or extend the library to meet this requirement.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to your response.

[Tried]

-Use the official document https://fullcalendar.io/docs#views

-and this (Result of asking chatGPT)
but this way can't use the default function of the full calendar

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentMonth = ('0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const daysInMonth = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate(); 
    const allDays = [];
    for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
      const daydata = {
        sortId: day,
        id: currentYear + '-' + currentMonth + '-' + day,
        title: currentMonth + '月' + day + '日',
      };
      allDays.push(daydata);
    }


    const events = [
      {
        title: 'Event 1',
        start: '2023-06-26T10:00:00',
        end: '2023-06-26T12:00:00',
        resourceId: '2023-06-24',
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 2',
        start: '2023-06-26T12:00:00',
        end: '2023-06-26T14:00:00',
        resourceId: '2023-06-26',
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 3',
        start: '2023-06-26T09:00:00',
        end: '2023-06-26T20:00:00',
        resourceId: '2023-06-1',
      },
    ];

    const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
      plugins: [resourceTimeline, timeGrid, dayGrid, list],
      initialView: 'resourceTimelineFourDays',
      slotDuration: '01:00:00',
      slotLabelInterval: '01:00',
      slotMinTime: '00:00:00',
      slotMaxTime: '24:00:00',
      locale: 'ja',
      resourceOrder: 'sortId',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineFourDays,resourceTimegridFourDays,dayGridMonth,listMonth',
      },
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
      resources: allDays,
      views: {
        resourceTimelineFourDays: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { days: 4 },
          buttonText: '4 day',
        },
        resourceTimegridFourDays: {
          type: 'timeGrid',
          duration: { months: 1 },
          buttonText: '1month Grid',
        },
      },
      events: events,
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiVKI.png)

My vision is about this image

Comment: Isn't the dayGridWeek view what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, that approach does not align with my vision.

Comment: Then I guess you do it on your own.  There are a large number of grid/spreadsheet controls that would enable your vision.  You'd have to handle the calendar aspects yourself, but there's not that much to it.

Comment: `Is there a way to achieve this functionality with the full calendar?`...no. The [Vertical Resource View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view) does exactly what you're asking, but just with the opposite axes. It cannot, at the time of writing, be changed through configuration. You _could_ consider trying to adjust its code and making your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) based on it, but a) that's a lot of work, and b) it's potentially a lot more work over time to maintain it and keep it compatible with future fullCalendar versions...

Comment: ...so I would suggest you consider carefully whether it's 100% necessary to have the layout exactly as you've asked for, or whether the existing view would in fact meet your needs, given that the functionality is identical, and the layout is basically just turned round by 90 degrees. That would save you a lot of time and trouble compared to the alternative. (Of course your other option is to [request a feature](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) but then you have to wait for it to be accepted, developed and released, and you have nothing in the meantime.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Considering the future maintenance and development costs, I am starting to question whether this UI design is appropriate in the first place. I would like to seek advice based on the approach of implementing as much as possible using the default functionality. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What kind of advice do you need about that? First study the documentation, try to implement it, and then ask us if you get stuck. Looking at your existing code though, you have already done 99% of the work